# update item in datagridview visualbasic 2010

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I update item in the DataGridView? If item already exists I want to update qty. If item doesn't exist I want to add new row.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim price As Integer = 80
    Dim qty As Integer = 1
    Dim total As Integer
    total = qty * price
    Dim food As String = "SISIG"
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim a As Integer
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For a = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value = food Then
                qty = CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells("QUANTITY").Value) + 1
                index = a

            End If
        Next
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(food, qty, price, total)
    End If
    total = qty * price
    DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Value = food
    DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value = qty
    DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value = price
    DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value = total
```

Comment: Most people would use databinding and perhaps some sort of underlying class collection.  Controls make horrible data containers

Answer (score 0):

You would have to replace:

```
    For a = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value = food Then
            qty = CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells("QUANTITY").Value) + 1
            index = a
        End If
    Next
```

with:

```
    For a = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value = food Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells("QUANTITY").Value += 1
        End If
    Next
```

The value of a cell is not read-only but can be changed.

Comment: @John John, Is this the answer you were looking for; it has been two days